# How can I do custom model binding with HttpTrigger in Azure Functions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function that is a POST endpoint.  The JSON object sent contains a datetime string and the POCO model receiving the request has that datetime defined as a string.  My issue is that the string is converted in the model binding before setting the value of the POCO object to a datetime format other than the machines and therefore it fails with "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".
Can I add some custom model binder that treats all incoming DateTime's in a certain format or even better do that on endpoint basis?

Regards,
Oskar

Comment: Can you give more details, does the probléme occur when sending your request  or to the azure function applications, you mentioned that the type is string so it's shouldn't try to parse it.

Comment: Sorry, I've resolved this issue by reading the request.Body into string and running Json.Deserialize into a model.